# Wait Facebook Callback result to return result

Tags: android, libgdx, facebook-android-sdk

I'm Trying To Return the Result For My Login Method Using `Facebook Api 4.5` 
But the Problem is when the result return Before Callback Method

My Code :

```
public class FacebookServiceImpl implements FacebookService {

   private AndroidLauncher androidLauncher;
   public CallbackManager callbackManager;

   private boolean loginSuccess;

   public FacebookServiceImpl(AndroidLauncher androidLauncher) {
      this.androidLauncher = androidLauncher;
   }

    public boolean login() {
      callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

      List<String> permission = new ArrayList<>();
      CallbackManager cm;

      permission.add("user_photos");
      LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    Gdx.app.log("onSuccess",loginSuccess+"");

                    loginSuccess = true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    Gdx.app.log("onCancel",loginSuccess+"");

                    loginSuccess = false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    Gdx.app.log("onError",loginSuccess+"");
                    loginSuccess = false;
                }
            });

    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(androidLauncher, permission);

    Gdx.app.log("Returning result",loginSuccess+"");
    return loginSuccess;
}
```

}
The Console Log "Returning Result " **BEFORE** "onSuccess"

so i want to wait the LoginManager to finish executing before return the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you actually want to do this you can try this,

But i think you should call a method if the login was successful and run that code, instead of checking if the condition is true and then run the code

```
public boolean login(final MyListener myListener) {
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    List<String> permission = new ArrayList<>();
    CallbackManager cm;

    permission.add("user_photos");
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    Gdx.app.log("onSuccess",loginSuccess.toString());

                    myListener.success(true);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    Gdx.app.log("onCancel",loginSuccess.toString());

                    myListener.success(false);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    Gdx.app.log("onError",loginSuccess.toString());
                    myListener.success(false);
                }
            });

    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(androidLauncher, permission);

    Gdx.app.log("Returning result",loginSuccess.toString());
}

interface MyListener{
    void success(boolean result);
}

...
login(new MyListener() {
            @Override
            public void success(boolean result) {
                //Some Stuff
            }
        });
```

Comment: You Save My Day :)